# Cluster wide lock via a shared file system limitations

Tags: java, java-8, locking, cluster-computing

I have a couple of nodes in my system that form a single logical cluster. There is a very sensitive flow that requires the nodes to synchronize on a critical section.

For various reasons, I cannot use a distributed framework like hazelcast.

I have a mitigation though. All of the nodes are connected to a shared file system.

I figured I could leverage this to implement a simple and hopefully reliable cluster wide lock.

I am programming in Java (1.8):

```
// 'file' is a path shared between the nodes. 
FileChannel fc = FileChannel.open(Paths.get(file), StandardOpenOption.APPEND);
FileLock lock = fc.lock();

System.out.println("Critical section"); // may take up to two minutes

lock.release();
```

My question: are there any limitations to this approach? I am guessing this is pretty sensitive to underlying OS, the file system and its configuration.

I am interested to know when this will *not* work.

Comment: Well, you already said it. It depends on the underlying OS, file system and configuration. Some systems consider locks only as advisory rather than mandatory, others may automatically release them after a timeout, etc. Since you have an actual configuration, you can find out whether it works sufficiently with that configuration.

Comment: @Holger, thanks. My situation is more complicated. The system is delivered to customers. I do have an official support matrix but I am wondering whether to go there. It may be that this does not work on a very wide range of configurations- dooming the approach. Based on the documentation, I guess I am going to drop this..

Comment: See this question which is related: https://stackoverflow.com/questions/50499598/how-to-reliably-update-a-file-in-a-shared-file-system    The actual lock on Windows is working reliably, but I am having problems with coordinating other file updates being strictly synchronized to the file lock.   If I lock the actual file itself, I am not able to update it in a safe way.  Maybe that helps?